# How to get only value of sql query without header using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I tried to fetch only DB value using groovy script but result includes the value along with header.

```
def res = con.rows("select fkuserid from tblUserCardDetail where cardValue='111633072'" )
log.info "The User ID from DB is :" + res
```

Result is coming like this : 
Mon Apr 25 06:51:07 PDT 2016:INFO:The User ID from DB is :[[fkuserid:2951]]

I want only value : 2951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Groovy SQL returns a result, it returns it as a `Map`-like object, a [GroovyRowResult](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/GroovyRowResult.html). Since you're using `rows()` you're getting a list of `GroovyRowResult`s.

If the query will always return a single record (or nothing at all), then you can use `firstRow()` instead of `rows()`. Then, you can access the `fkuserid` property/key to get the value:

```
def res = con.firstRow("select fkuserid from tblUserCardDetail where cardValue='111633072'" )
log.info "The User ID from DB is :" + res.fkuserid
```

Comment: One more query: When i pass variable directly in my query it throws error "The conversion of the nvarchar value '1005203406848' overflowed an int column" -------def sn = context.expand( '${serialNumber_Valid}' ) ------def res = con.firstRow("select fkuserid from tblUserCardDetail where cardValue=" + sn )

Comment: What exactly is your query?

Comment: You can see in my question i passed static value and it fetch the data but i want it to be dynamic. So i stored the value in the global properties and use it to provide input to my query. When i print the sn value i get the same result which i passed as static but when i use variable it throws error.

Comment: It seems that in the query with the hard-coded value, the `cardValue` column is expected to be a varchar, yet in the query with the variable, the `cardValue` is expected to be an integer. Since the hard-coded query works, then the issue is probably in the formatting of the query. Try this: `"select fkuserid from tblUserCardDetail where cardValue='$sn'"`.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858184/how-to-use-global-property-value-in-connection-string-using-groovy