# How to use global property value in connection string using groovy

Tags: jdbc, groovy, soapui

I tried to use global property value in connection so that i can change it from one place and it will apply in all my script.
This is my connection string and it works fine when i put the IP directly in the string

```
def dbName = context.expand( '${DB_Name}' )
def dbUser = context.expand( '${DB_Username}' )
def dbPass = context.expand( '${DB_Password}' )
def con = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.111.111:1433;" + "databaseName=" + dbName, dbUser, dbPass, 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')
```

But when i put the global properties, it throws error "The TCP/IP connection to the host '192.168.111.111', port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."."

```
def dbServer = context.expand( '${DB_Server}' )
def dbPort = context.expand( '${DB_Port}' )
def dbName = context.expand( '${DB_Name}' )
def dbUser = context.expand( '${DB_Username}' )
def dbPass = context.expand( '${DB_Password}' )
def con = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://'$dbServer':1433;" + "databaseName=" + dbName, dbUser, dbPass, 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you've put the `$dbServer` address in quotes, it should be

```
def con = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://$dbServer:1433;" + "databaseName=" + dbName, dbUser, dbPass, 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')
```

Or (templating all the things, not just the server)

```
def con = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://$dbServer:1433;databaseName=$dbName", dbUser, dbPass, 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')
```

Comment: oops. Silly mistake. Thanks :)